# R: Why this two different results (fit curve) from two different software for the same points?

Tags: r, excel, curve-fitting, equation

I have this equation problem. I want to plot and fit (polyniomial 2°) this point data frame `df.1`:

```
df.1 
      x      y
    1902    0.01
    1930    0.1 
    1950    0.5
    1980    1
    2014    1.8
```

the code is:

```
lm(df.1[,2] ~ poly(df.1[,1],2))
```

the result is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = df.1[, 2] ~ poly(df.1[, 1], 2))

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  poly(df.1[, 1], 2)1  poly(df.1[, 1], 2)2  
             0.6620               1.4660               0.3339
```

The equation plot is :

```
ggplot(df.1, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=df.1[,2],x=df.1[,1]),show.legend = T,linetype="dashed",method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size = 0.4,se=T)+
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label..,..rr.label..,sep = "~")),formula =y ~ poly(x, 2),parse = TRUE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"))
```

[image]

Now, if i use other software, like excel or STATISTICA 10, the coefficient result from 2° fit polynomial curve is:

```
intercept  366.199
poly x   0.389864
poly x^2   0.000103743
```

[image]

The values in y (if i want to find the values of all fit curve),  are right with excel equation, but the question is: Why R fit result in different values (moreover with only positive coefficient values)?

Comment: Hint: the abscissa are interpreted differently in excel and in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lm(df.1[,2] ~ poly(df.1[,1], 2, raw = T))` will return the same values as in Excel.

> poly {stats} raw if true, use raw and not orthogonal polynomials.
>
> The orthogonal polynomial is summarized by the coefficients, which can
>   be used to evaluate it via the three-term recursion given in Kennedy &
>   Gentle (1980, pp. 343–4), and used in the predict part of the code.

[Source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257406/polynomial-regression-why-do-excel-coefficients-differ-from-rs)